# How to print (or use) the values of geometry properties in document page?

Tags: geometry

I have problems with `geometry` package. I would like to find out parameters of my page (layout) such as textwidth, layoutheight etc. I want to have a dynamic layout of my page without number or constants..

I have found many pages, but I haven't been able to do that correctly so far.

For example:
How to print the value of layoutwidth (from package manual `width=\Gm@layoutwidth`) to the document or use it in TiKZ parameters for objects.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I see couple things in your question that could be improved, since currently the question isn't quite clear. (1) What is a "dynamic layout"? (2) Please ask a more specific question, like: How to make a TikZ picture occupy the whole layout width? (I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if it is, there may be other solutions than tweaking stuff manually by detecting the layout width.) (3) It would be better to provide an example code.

Comment: If you add `verbose` to the options to `geometry`, all relevant dimensions are reported in the `.log` file

Comment: If you use the `[pass,verbose]` option to `geometry`, it uses the unaltered default dimensions of the class, while still giving, as egreg points out, the dimensions in the log file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `verbose` option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
  a4paper, twoside,
  layout=b5paper,
  left=2cm, hmarginratio=2:1, includemp, marginparwidth=43pt,
  bottom=1cm, foot=.7cm, includefoot,
  heightrounded,
  columnsep=1cm,
  verbose
]{geometry}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

You'll find, in the `.log` file,

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <custom>
* layout(width,height): (500.7685pt,711.3189pt)
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 2:1
* modes: includefoot includemp twoside heightrounded 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 415.41025pt, 28.45274pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(85.35913pt, 597.50702pt, 28.45274pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=365.41025pt
* \textheight=574.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=6.18275pt
* \topmargin=-16.97835pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=19.91684pt
* \marginparwidth=43.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=28.45274pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

The parameters are available at runtime: for example `\Gm@layoutwidth` is a dimension parameter and you can access it whenever you need a length; just add in the document preamble

```
\newcommand{\geometrylen}[1]{\csname Gm@#1\endcsname}
```

and you can do

```
width=\geometrylen{layoutwidth}
```

where a length is expected.

You can even say

```
\texttt{\the\geometrylen{layoutwidth}}
```

and get `500.7685pt` printed.